# How to create full screen mode for a youtube application with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

We have created an application to watch videos on youtube but also with the possibility to search on the Internet.

The problem is that on the full screen side I can't make it work the way I want it to full screen, but when I want to exit full screen, I get two windows instead of one or if I get stuck with a window, I delete QWebEngineView. I don't have much experience with this Qt framework and I will be grateful if you help me.

Since I use PyQt5 version 5.13.2

That's all the code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1200, 800)

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")

        self.hboxlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.hboxlayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.hboxlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hboxlayout.setObjectName("hboxlayout")

        #bara de navigare pe care sun asezate butoanele beak,inaninte etc.
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.tbNavigate = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.tbNavigate.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.tbNavigate.setObjectName("tbNavigate")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.tbNavigate)


        self.browser=QWebEngineView(MainWindow)
        self.browser.load(QUrl('https://youtube.com'))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
        self.browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(self.FullscreenRequest)

        #butonul back
        self.actionBack = QtWidgets.QAction("Back")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icone/back.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionBack.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionBack.setObjectName("actionBack")

        #butonul inaite
        self.actionForward = QtWidgets.QAction("Forward")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icone/next.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionForward.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionForward.setObjectName("actionForward")



        #butonul refresh
        self.actionRefresh = QtWidgets.QAction("Reload this page")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icone/baseline_refresh_black_18dp.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionRefresh.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionRefresh.setObjectName("actionRefresh")

        #Butonul home
        self.actionHome = QtWidgets.QAction("Home")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icone/home (1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionHome.setIcon(icon5)
        self.actionHome.setObjectName("actionHome")

        self.actionFileClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFileClose.setObjectName("actionFileClose")

        #Sll icon or no-sll
        self.httpsicon = QLabel()
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icone/lock.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal,QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        #self.httpsicon.setIcon(icon6)
        self.httpsicon.setObjectName("httpsicon")






        #functinare butonelor pe bara de navigare
        self.tbNavigate.addAction(self.actionBack)
        self.tbNavigate.addAction(self.actionForward)
        self.tbNavigate.addAction(self.actionRefresh)
        self.tbNavigate.addAction(self.actionHome)
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.httpsicon)

        #self.tbNavigate.addSeparator()



        self.actionBack.triggered.connect( self.browser.back)
        self.actionForward.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.actionRefresh.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        self.actionHome.triggered.connect(self.navigateHome)

        #self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



        self.addressbar =QLineEdit()
        self.addressbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.addressbar)
        #citeste url
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlBar)


    def navigateHome(self):

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

    def navigate_to_url(self):  
        q = QUrl(self.addressbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == "":
            q.setScheme("https")

        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    def update_urlBar(self, q):

        if q.scheme() == 'https':
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap("icone/ssl.png"))

        else:
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap("icone/lock.png"))

        self.addressbar.setText(q.toString())
        self.addressbar.setCursorPosition(0)

    def FullscreenRequest(self, request):

       print("requested")

       if(request.toggleOn()):
          request.accept()

          self.browser.setParent(None)

          self.browser.showFullScreen()

       else:
          request.accept()
          self.browser.showNormal()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
#sys.exit(app.exec_())
app.exec_()
```

The problem is here:

```
def FullscreenRequest(self, request):

       print("requested")

       if(request.toggleOn()):
          request.accept()

          self.browser.setParent(None)

          self.browser.showFullScreen()

       else:
          request.accept()
          self.browser.showNormal()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to reset the QWebEngineView as centralwidget.

---

#### TL; DR;

If you are going to use Qt Designer then you should not modify the class generated by pyuic as indicated in the warning, and one of the reasons is that this class is not a widget, so many times you will have problems, but in your case you have practically deleted what Qt Designer has provided so I rewrote your application.

Going to the problem, by setting `setParent(None)` you are indicating that the widget is not part of the window and therefore will be part of another new window where that widget is the toplevel, so if you want to restore it you must set it as centralWidget so that Be part of the window again.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.tbNavigate = QtWidgets.QToolBar(orientation=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.tbNavigate)

        action_data = [
            ("Back", "icone/next.png", self.browser.back),
            ("Forward", "icone/next.png", self.browser.forward),
            (
                "Reload this page",
                "icone/baseline_refresh_black_18dp.png",
                self.browser.reload,
            ),
            ("Home", "icone/home (1).png", self.navigateHome),
        ]

        for text, icon_path, slot in action_data:
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(
                QtGui.QPixmap(icon_path), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off
            )
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(text, icon=icon, triggered=slot, parent=self)
            self.tbNavigate.addAction(action)

        self.httpsicon = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.httpsicon)

        self.addressbar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.addressbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.addressbar)
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlBar)

        self.browser.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://youtube.com"))
        global_settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()

        for attr in (
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled,
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled,
        ):
            global_settings.setAttribute(attr, True)
        self.browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(self.FullscreenRequest)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def navigateHome(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QtCore.QUrl(self.addressbar.text())
        if not q.scheme():
            q.setScheme("https")
        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QUrl)
    def update_urlBar(self, url):
        pixmap = (
            QtGui.QPixmap("icone/ssl.png")
            if url.scheme() == "https"
            else QtGui.QPixmap("icone/lock.png")
        )
        self.httpsicon.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.addressbar.setText(url.toString())
        self.addressbar.setCursorPosition(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineFullScreenRequest")
    def FullscreenRequest(self, request):
        request.accept()
        if request.toggleOn():
            self.browser.setParent(None)
            self.browser.showFullScreen()
        else:
            self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
            self.browser.showNormal()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can't test it right now on my system, but I think that it would be an important aspect: are the QWebEngineFullScreenRequest and fullScreenRequested window manager aware on Linux? I remember you said you use Linux also, so I think you can provide some insight about this matter: different WM behave in different way with fullscreen "hints" (and also behave differently for "virtual" desktop/screens).

Comment: @musicamante The fullScreenRequested is a signal that emits a request (QWebEngineFullScreenRequest) that indicates that some resource (video or image) wants to occupy the entire QWebEngineView or wants to be restored to the previous state if it already occupies all the QWebEngineView, but the OP wants the resource to occupy all the screen that implies that the QWebEngineView occupies the screen, so for that it did: setParent (None) and showFullScreen but the reverse case is to reset the QWebEngineView to be the centralWidget, and that was my solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand that; what I meant is that some window managers behave differently with graphic server requests, like window/desktop switching or even wm "normalizing" requests to the window.

Comment: @musicamante Could you explain yourself in greater detail, what possible unexpected behavior do you think might happen?

Comment: How would one exit fullscreen when escape is pressed?