# How to make vlc video go fulllscreen in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, fullscreen, vlc, video-player

I am trying to develop a simple video player using python-vlc and pyqt5. But the problem is that I am unable to make it go fullscreen. When I click the fullscreen button self.frame.showFullScreen() does nothing. I even tried the solution posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293382/python-qt-application-with-vlc-does-not-show-fullscreen)

But unfortunately it did not help me. I am kinda new to PyQt5 and VLC thing but I am unable to sort it out.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import vlc
import time
import os
import platform

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 421))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(28, 29, 32);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 791, 421))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
   "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)\n"
   "}")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 469, 241, 91))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 469, 241, 91))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.mediaplayer = vlc.MediaPlayer()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Load_Video)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.go_fullscreen)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click Load Video to play  your favourite videos !"))

        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load Video"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Fullscreen"))


    def Load_Video(self):
        """Open a media file in a MediaPlayer
        """

        dialog_txt = "Choose Media File"
        filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, dialog_txt, os.path.expanduser('~'))
        if not filename:
            return

        # getOpenFileName returns a tuple, so use only the actual file name
        self.media = self.instance.media_new(filename[0])

        # Put the media in the media player
        self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)

        # Set the title of the track as window title
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", self.media.get_meta(0)))

        if platform.system() == "Linux": # for Linux using the X Server
            self.mediaplayer.set_xwindow(int(self.frame.winId()))
        elif platform.system() == "Windows": # for Windows
            self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(int(self.frame.winId()))
        elif platform.system() == "Darwin": # for MacOS
            self.mediaplayer.set_nsobject(int(self.frame.winId()))

        self.mediaplayer.play()
        time.sleep(2)

    def go_fullscreen(self):
        self.frame.showFullScreen()  # This is the part where the code doesn't work, it does nothing.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there anthing I am doing wrong? if it is so then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know (almost) anything about PyQT5 but if I'm referring to the documentation, calling [`showFullScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) only affects [windows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isWindow), so you have to detach your frame from the main window before.

```
def go_fullscreen(self):
    self.frame.setParent(None)
    self.frame.showFullScreen()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response. It worked. I just had a last question that how can we bring it back again in its original state? Once again Thank you for your response.

Comment: To return from full-screen mode, call `showNormal()`. I think you need *reparent* frame. Probably you need to `installEventFilter()` to catch `Esc` key press or anything else.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401485/15239951) can help you. The author of this answer is the one who edited your post!

Comment: @Just_A_Coder `self.frame.setParent(self.centralWidget); self.show()`; do note that you didn't use any [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (which is usually not a very good idea), so you'll need to reset the geometry manually (and this is one of the reasons for which not using layouts is a really bad choice). Also, avoid trying to edit the output of pyuic files, that's another bad practice.

Comment: It Worked. Thank you everyone who helped me to solve this problem. Thank you for you advice musicamante. I will look forward to use Layouts in pyqt5, and I will try not to edit from output of pyuic files. Once again, Thank you everyone who supported me.